# Jquery .getJSON Not Running console.log(data)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am currently on the weather app and I'm trying to set up connecting to the Dark Sky API and get the contents of JSON file, my local weather. I'm copying my code from codepen, so it my look a little bare. Will also connect to my [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Cavitation90/pen/bRqvpj?editors=1012) project.

JS JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var lon;
  var lat; 
  //Get GEO LOCATION
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
      lat = position.coords.latitude
      lon = position.coords.longitude;
      $("#data").html("latitude: " + lat + "<br>longitude: " + lon);

  //KEY AND GET TO DARK SKY API 
  var api = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/04387baec37bab4248564577c8134df7/"+lat+","+lon;
  $.getJSON(api, function(data){   
      console.log(data.latitiude); 
  });  

});
};

});
```

In my $.getJSON the console will not log the contents of the api connection to Dark Sky.

Here is the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X4UhrbNmUr8&list=PLHdCowjFIBmLRvwkK0UNz0OA10pYI4H0g&index=3) (not the best tutorial in the world, but its helping a lot) where the guy is able to do just that and can log data from the JSON  in the console. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**, not just on a third-party site like codepen, jsfiddle, etc.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "the console will not log"? Are you getting errors? If the line is getting hit, something will get logged, or an error will display.

Comment: Sorry, still a newbie, thank you for the edits. Let me clarify. My desired behavior is that in my console I want to display the data in the JSON file that I'm connecting to, so I'm using console.log(data.latitude) within my $.getJSON function, but it will not display any data in the console.